# How to fill a list with null values so it is a specific length?

Tags: dart

I have a situation where I have a list that can be at most 4 elements.

However, if I have only 1-3 elements to put in that list, how can I fill the remainder with null values?

For example, a List<int?> of length 4 with 2 given elements, should result in:

`[1,3] -> [1,3,null,null]`

Here's what I'm doing, but maybe there is a better way

```
 List.generate(4, (index) {
      try {
        final id = given.elementAt(index);
        return id;
      } catch (error) {
        return null;
      }
    });
```

Comment: I'd personally use `if (index < given.length)` instead of using exceptions for control flow, and if you want a fixed-size `List`, you should use `List.generate(..., growable: false)`, but otherwise that approach seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest version would probably be:

```dart
[for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) i < given.length ? given[i] : null]
```

You can use `List.generate`, but in this case, the function is simple enough that a list literal can do the same thing more efficiently.
(Or, as @jamesdlin says, if you want a fixed-length list, use `List.generate`).

A more indirect variant could be:

```dart
 List<GivenType?>.filled(4, null)..setAll(0, given)
```

where you create a list of four `null`s first, then write the `given` list into it. It's probably just more complicated and less efficient.